# How to group rows by their value in a certain column and then export them to corresponding new spreadsheets using Google Sheets API

Tags: api, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I were to start with a data set like the one below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yrno.png]

How could I then group the data by each colour and then retrieve separate datasets with those grouped values, as below:

[image: 0]

So that new spreadsheets can be created for each colour ('Red', 'Blue' etc.) containing the corresponding data. I've spent the whole day experimenting with json, update requests, if loops and foreach formulas, but haven't had any luck as I'm still very new to all this. My code so far is as follows (it pertains to a different data set, I've used a simplified example above):

```
function sortdata() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1xyi-9rfxggNexdBFBVVbkaIVQVBmIoWcpok8BelZTuI")
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  var sheetname = sheet.getName()
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange()
  var values = datarange.getValues()
  var datarangesorted = datarange.offset(1,0).sort( {
                                        column: 4,
                                        ascending: true,
                                        } )
  var rowssorted = datarangesorted.getValues()
  var newsheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet()
  newsheet.getRange("A1").setFormula("=UNIQUE('GrigoleitBlöcke'!D2:D)")
  var unfilteredmanufacturers = newsheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
  var filteredmanufacturers = unfilteredmanufacturers.filter(String)
  Logger.log(filteredmanufacturers)

  var filtered = filteredmanufacturers.forEach(function(eachmanufacturer){
  var filteredrows = rowssorted.filter(function(rowssorted){
                            if (rowssorted[2] === eachmanufacturer) {
                            return rowssorted }
                            })
})
  Logger.log(filtered)
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: Do you want to create new spreadsheets or new sheets inside of spreadsheets?

Comment: I'd like to create new spreadsheets.

Comment: What would be the name of the sheets for each spreadsheet?

Comment: You seem to be creating sheets and not spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete function that creates the Spreadsheets.

It also renames the first sheet to one of the unique colors

And it also places the data for that color in the renamed spreadsheet.

It creates a file to copy and then deletes it at the end.  This can be a handy way to create a template that you want to use repeatedly.  You can create the copy by hand with any kind of formatting that you wish.

```
function newSpreadsheets() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const drg=dsh.getRange(1,1,dsh.getLastRow(),2);
  const vA=drg.getValues();
  var sshts={pA:[]};
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(!sshts.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      sshts[r[0]]=[];
      sshts[r[0]].push(r[1]);//an array of all column B values for each color
      sshts.pA.push(r[0]);//array of different colors
    }else{
      sshts[r[0]].push(r[1]);
    }
  });
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid');
  //you can us the following file as a template if you wish by creating it yourself by hand and then saving it in some folder
  var fileid=SpreadsheetApp.create('temp').getId();//this file gets deleted at the end
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileid);
  sshts.pA.forEach(function(sh){
    var f=file.makeCopy(sh, folder);//makes a copy of the temp file and names it sh which is one of the colors
    var fid=f.getId();    
    var css=SpreadsheetApp.openById(fid);
    var tsh=css.getSheets()[0].setName(sh);//this is the only sheet in the new spreadsheet and it gets named with the same name as the spreadsheet
    var vB=[];
    sshts[sh].forEach(function(e,i){vB.push([sh,e]);});//this line loads color data into the array which will be loaded into the sheet
    tsh.getRange(1,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);//this is the line that loads data into the sheet
  });
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).setTrashed(true);//this is the temp file and it get's put in the trash
}
```

This was my test data:

```
RED,10
RED,20
RED,30
RED,40
BLUE,50
BLUE,70
BLUE,90
```

This is an image of the two sheets in the two spreadsheets

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! To your other comment, I would like each spreadsheet to have one sheet which has the same name as the spreadsheet, e.g. 'Red' with one sheet named 'Red'. I also have two questions about the code, what does 'pA' signify and 'function(sh)'? Thanks again.

Comment: I property Array.  I use a lot of simple variable names because I don't like long variable names.

Comment: It took me a while to work through everything but I think I've finally understood the whole code and learnt a lot about javascript in the process. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help!